# Complete order of Stripe payment, get refund

Tags: magento2, payment, magento2.3.3, stripe

[image]

I got some message like this in my email:

Payment Transaction Failed
Reason
Delivery date is required. Please select delivery date and proceed.
Checkout Type
onepage

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any log generated in system.log or exception.log?

Comment: Thanks, I try to search stripe in the log file but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a date of shipping or date of birth module at your checkout, please ensure that a validation is running on the front-end which prevents the customer from placing the order with an empty date. That module throws an error that this field is required, however it does that AFTER the payment is collected, which would create this problem. I would recommend contacting the developer of that module to ensure that front-end field validation is added. This would alert the customer that they left the date field incomplete before placing the order.

Comment: Yes, it's missing the delivery date in that order!